# img with position absolute inside a div with position absolute

Tags: html, css

So I've got a main div element with position: relative.
Inside of it there's another div with position: absolute.
And inside that div I want to have  that will also have position absolute to it's parent element, but I can't get it to work.

Is there any workaround without having to nest that img inside another div? (I had problems with that due to the shape of my overlay and I will want to transform the image)

```css
.1 {  position: relative;  }

.2 {  position: absolute;  }

.2 img {  position: absolute;  }
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <img src="foo.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing quotation mark in the first `<div>` and in `<img>`.

Comment: You can't begin a class with a number.

Comment: This question is almost impossible to answer as it stands. Can you please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including both absolute image paths, and CSS that gives **sizes** to your elements.

Comment: Class naming rules: Must begin with a letter (A-Z or a-z).

Answer (score 1):

It works!

`position: absolute`, as far as I know, is relative to its first parent element that is not `position: static`, which is what every element is positioned by default.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It indeed works, I must have done some terrible typo or something in my code that I havent found for good 10 minutes. Thank you for assuring me that it works and im so sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Lol! No worries! If you posted your HTML code in another question and provide a link here, I could help you debug it! Also, please consider accepting my question if it answers your question :) More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)